# OrientDB: how to log exected queries

Tags: orientdb

is there a way to show executed queries with the value of passed named parameters, I tried query profiler in enterprise edition, but it only shows the base query.
e.g.
instead of: `SELECT from Blog WHERE date BETWEEN :from AND :to`
it should be: `SELECT from Blog WHERE date BETWEEN 1-1-2015 AND 1-2-2015`
thanks.

Comment: How do you execute the query?

Comment: i understand the purpose if your question, you mean as long as i executed the query from java, i can log the parameters, right?, the problem is that sometimes the returned result is empty although i am sure that there must be some results, so what i wanted is a way to copy this executed query to orientdb console and play with it untill i get what is wrong with my code.

Comment: I wanted to know sorry from where you execute the query. Java/Nodejs/Python from remote?